# Install Shell Commands for Atom [windows]

Tags: command-line, atom-editor

in atom editor on mac, there is

```
Atom > Install Shell Commands
```

but on windows, there is no anything like that

i find the cmd files for atom in this folder

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\cli
```

in this directory the atom line work in command line. but in other directories it not work

Comment: On Windows, the command should run during installtion. You should be able to run it from Atom's command palette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find solution for my problem

first i reinstall atom with this command

```
$ choco install atom
```

you need to install Chocolatey before use choco command

then i find cmd files of atom in

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\atom\bin
```

then i set this `PATH` by this command

```
$ setx path "%path%;C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\atom\bin"
```

now i can use `atom` and `apm` commands

i hope that can help anyone